Who was the Rabbi Of Rabbi Yitzchak Kanpanton?
Another question regarding the same topic, the rabbi of the Mahari Abuhav and other big rishonim was the great Rabbi Yitzchak Kanpanton. Who was his rabbi?

According to the excerpt here - https://torah.org/torah-portion/hamaayan-5766-behar/ taken from Artscroll's Early Acharonim, not much of his earlier life is known. We only really know his talmidim and his authored work.

@Dov also Artscroll Rishonim has a small entry. There is also an audio by R' Dovid Sackton on his sefer Darkei haGemara

@YDJ there is loads written about him - just not much if any about his earlier years...

The Hebrew wiki states that his father R' Ya'akov was a student of R' Chasdai Crescas, and it's reasonable to speculate that R' Yitzchak Kanpanton studied from his father (comparable to how the Rambam studied from his father who was in turn a student of the Ri Migash). (Also, for the sake of specificity, the Mahari Abuhav you mentioned is Rabbi Yitzchak Abuhav II of Castille).

I didn't know that there was another mahari abuhav other then of castille, I read the hebrew wiki too but didnt saw about the father of the rav, very very likely. thank you very much

@RakhemHaokip R' Yitzchak Abuhav II's great-great-grandfather was R' Yitzchak Abuhav I, author of מנורת המאור (and he also lived some of his life in Castille). The quote from the wiki about R' Kanpanton (beginning of the bio section) was, "נולד בקסטיליה שבספרד בשנת ק"כ (1360) לאביו רבי יעקב שהיה מתלמידיו של רבי חסדאי קרשקש".

The Chida in Shem HaGedolim (Maareches Seforim, Maareches Daled, 55) mentions him with regard to his authored sefer, Darkei Gemara (דרכי גמרא):

Rabbi Yitzchak Kanpanton, who was a great sage in Castile and whose works were printed several times. His students were two great figures of the generation: Mahari Abuhav and Mahari Di Leon

Rabbi Yitzchak  Kanpanton was back then refered to as "the Gaon", not commonly used in that generation (Sefer HaYuchasin HaShalem, p. 2).
Of Rabbi Avraham Zacuto (אברהם זכות) it is said that when he was 6-7 years old, he met Rabbi Kanpanton. The story goes as follows:

When he was six or seven years old, he saw the elder Rabbi Yitzchak Kanpanton, the leader of all the exiles of Castile, whom his generation referred to with the title "Gaon," a designation not commonly used in those days. The sight of "the pious and humble one, imbued with the spirit of the holy G-d," made a profound impression on the young boy, leading him to write in his old age: "One who sees his face is as if receiving the Divine Presence." (Sefer HaYuchasin HaShalem, p. 2)


Though great info on Rabbi Kanpanton, this doesn't seem to answer the OP's question of who was his own rabbi.

My bad, I misread the question.
